# JS: Input user name and print it out

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, input-field

I'm the beginner of JS. I try to get input from the HTML form. And print words out from function. I have read JS in W3. However, it keeps going wrong. Could somebody give me a hand.

HTML - about the form

```
<form method="get">
<h2>Please leave your contact information for us</h2>

<label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Your First Name"><br>

<label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Your last Name"><br>

<label for="email">E-mail:</label>
<input type="e-mail" id="email" name="eMail"><br>


<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="passWord"><br>

<label for="suGession">sub gesstion:</label><br>
<textarea name="suggestion" id="suGession" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<p>What do you usually cook?</p>
<input type="text">
<button type="submit" onclick="welcome()">Give Us Help</button>

</form>
```

My JS code

```
var first = document.getElementById("FirstName");
var last = document.getElementById("LastName");     

function welcome(){

    var welcomeF = "Welcome" + first +" "+ last;
    return welcomeF;

}

console.log(welcome());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use first.value to get the value of the element & use onSubmit attribute in  instead of using onclick.

Have a look at this code, I did some changes in your code.

Javacript :

```
    function welcome(){
    var first = document.getElementById("FirstName").value; 
    var last = document.getElementById("LastName").value;
    var welcomeF = "Welcome " + first +" "+ last;
    console.log(welcomeF);
    window.alert(welcomeF);
    return false; //To prevent it from going into next page.
}
```

Html :

```
    <form  onSubmit = "return welcome();">
    <h2>Please leave your contact information for us</h2>

    <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Your First Name"><br>

    <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Your last Name"><br>

    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="e-mail" id="email" name="eMail"><br>


    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="passWord"><br>

    <label for="suGession">sub gesstion:</label><br>
    <textarea name="suggestion" id="suGession" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
    <p>What do you usually cook?</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit" >Give Us Help</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shehroz Sheikh
It works right now!!

Could I asks the differences to use onsubmit and click?

Comment: OnSubmit is used on a form, and indicates that the information is to be submitted to the server.If you return false in the onSubmit function,page information will not send to the server.

We mostly use 'return false;' if we are validating that the user entered the right data or not! I mean validation by javascript.


Whereas , onclick can be used on anything,but it won't  help you in validation sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
var welcomeF = "Welcome" + first +" "+ last;
```

to:

```
var welcomeF = "Welcome" + first.value +" "+ last.value;
```

first and last are just references to the dom nodes, not the value in them