# Plugging values from HTML forms into JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm a novice coder and I have a general question.  I'm building my first proper website. It's an astronomy website for kids. One of the features I want is an online calculator which tells you your age on other planets.  The form would look like this:

1. Box where user would enter their age in years.
2. Drop down menu where user would pick any one of the other planets in the solar system.
3. Submit button.

When the submit button is pressed, the details from 1. and 2. would be passed into a function.  The function would then work out how old the user would be if they had been born on another planet.  For example, I'm 34, and Mercury has 88 days in a year so if I input my age and chose Mercury and pressed submit I would get back something like *"If you were born on Mercury you would be 141 years old".*

The problem is I don't know how to pass the user input from (1) and (2) into a function to do the calculation.  I've not included any code because I'm very new to all this and don't even know where to start. I've tried googling and looking through previous questions on this site and I've not been able to find anything which I can understand.  If you have any advice it would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: Input user name and print it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195709/js-input-user-name-and-print-it-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The HTML**

```
<!-- The age input box -->
<input type="number" id="age" placeholder="your age here">

<!-- The drop down with planets -->
<select id="planet">
<option value="0">Earth</option>
<option value="1">Mars</option>
<option value="2">Neptune</option>
<option value="3">Pluto</option>
</select>

<!-- The sumbit button -->
<button onclick="calculate()">Go!</button>

<!-- The text tag in which we will print the output -->
<p id="output"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function calculate(){
var age = document.getElementById("age").value; 
var planet = document.getElementById("planet").value;
var multipliers = [0.8, 2.5, 8.3, 0.12];

var new_age = age * multipliers[planet];
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "You would be " + new_age + " 
years old";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to write the code out.  I just have a quick follow-up question.  I'm sure I'm just overlooking something obvious, but when I paste the HTML code into my HTML file, and then paste the JS code into my JS file, fill in the fields and press submit, the form simply resets and I can't see the expected output. 

I can see the 'your age here' box, and I can see the planet drop down menu and the Go! button, just not the ```"you would be x"``` output in the ```<p id="output></p>``` tag.

Comment: @Shank I have corrected the code now. I forgot an "s" in "multipliers". And I rewrote the HTML for better. Try it now and customize for your needs.

Comment: That's brilliant.  Thanks very much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of an HTML input or select by using the `value` property:

```
document.getElementById('yourinputid').value;
```

I'd suggest storing the two form input values in variables and then passing them to your function that performs the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey cheack this out https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/**

```js
submit.onclick = function(event){

  var multipliers = [0.8, 2.5, 8.3, 0.12];
  var clientAge, 
  eachOptionIndex,
  optionArr,
  planetName,
  onPlanetAge,

clientAge = +age.value;
eachOptionIndex = +planet.value;
// get each option's value and convert it to Number 0,1,2,3

onPlanetAge = clientAge * multipliers[eachOptionIndex];

optionArr = planet.getElementsByTagName("option");
planetName = optionArr[eachOptionIndex].getAttribute("data-name");

   output.innerHTML ="If i was born on " + planetName + " i would be " + onPlanetAge + " years Old";

};
```

```html
 <input type="number" id="age" placeholder="your age here">

 <select id="planet">
        <option data-name="Earth" value="0">Earth</option>
        <option data-name="Mars" value="1">Mars</option>
        <option data-name="Neptune" value="2">Neptune</option>
         <option data-name="Pluto" value="3">Pluto</option>
 </select>

 <button type="submit" id="submit">Go!</button>

         <p id="output"></p>
```